# Enforce the user to enter a year

Tags: forms, oracle

I have an application form, where i placed text item where the user enter manually a year like for example: 2016.

I tried to enforce the user to enter correctly the year on its format, not for example charcters or numbers. 
Any way to that?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the form yearly and if so to make it work universally you could just convert to an int and check if intYear = currYear. I mean there are a lot of other fixes including if Year>= 2016- then allow which could still get you things like 9999 but then you could do a opposite. Although ultimately the most efficient would be getting the computers year which may propose challenges but would work for more year and only have problem with people who have incorrect year.

Comment: i think you miss understand me. what i want to enforce user to enter a valid year, he can enter any year he wants not exactly 2016.

Comment: Oh ok. So what I would try is to convert to string and check if length != 4 if you only want 4 digit years, and then to avoid character check to see if each character doesn't equal a 1or 2 or 3...

Comment: i will get in multiple loops. if for example the user entered 9124, this isn't a valid year, howcan i control that?

Comment: Can you have your front-end form generate a drop-list of valid values, forcing the user to select from the list?

Answer (score 0):

The year should be entered as a number. You can verify that it is an integer, that it is <= current year, and >= 1993 (for example), like this:

```
...  yr = round(yr) and yr between 1993 and extract (year from sysdate)
```

Honestly, I am not familiar with Oracle forms; this may be a check, for example, in an "if ... then ... else" structure in a stored procedure, and raise an error if the condition is not met. yr is the name of the input variable. If the user enters '2015' (with the single quotes) instead of 2015 (as a number) Oracle will likely convert it to a number, silently and without warning, and it will pass the test - but then you can safely assume the user really meant to enter 2015; no harm will result.